# What should I do after I have received a job offer if I am anticipating receiving another offer?

Tags: job-search, job-offer

I received a job offer from company A today but I am anticipating possibly receiving another job offer from company B later this week.

What should I say to company A? Obviously, I don't want to lose A's offer if B does not make a better offer.

Comment: possible duplicates that were posted today:  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113876/how-can-i-professionally-renege-an-offer-that-i-previously-accepted   https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113879/just-graduated-college-was-hired-and-now-i-have-another-offer   https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113878/how-to-respond-to-a-job-offer-when-waiting-for-a-counter-offer

Comment: you have posted a very similar question. Can you make up your mind at least on what you ask?

Answer (score 1):

I was in this exact situation recently, and the best thing you can do is tell A that you are waiting on another offer and give them a time frame, i.e. I will let you know at the end of the week.

You can tell A that you would much rather work with them but you want to hear the offer from B just in case there is a significant difference in the money offered. This way they won't think that they are a second choice and potentially drop the offer.

If A has a problem with waiting they will tell you and then you will have to make a decision, otherwise you can wait to hear from B and then choose whichever offer is best for you.

When I did this A asked me to give them a chance to match any offer made by B, easiest negotiation ever.